# Is it possible to have a WCF - Service standalone and let clients connect to it?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, service, callback

i created a program which shows a List on an dataGrid in WPF.
Its data for the list becomes it trough a service i references
via WCF  (its creates a single list entry and give it to the wpf program
via callback)

Now i want to have multiple wpf clients connecting to this specific
wcf - service, but i seem to have a little problem with that.

I want it that the WCF - Service is a standalone i need to start seperately
(via double click on .exe or whatever...)

And then i want to have a function in my wpf program where i can put URL/IP and let the client connect to the service i just started. ( I want it so that multiple clients can connect to the service and all client will recieve the same entrys)

Is there a solution for my problem ? I cant seem to think of one, since i need to add the wcf service to reference to my wpf client, with what i have currently everytime i start a client it will get entrys...but not all client the same cause the wcf service is hosted withhin the program itself kind of...

Thats not what i need/want, can someone point me in the right direction or can give me examples?

Thanks to all that are willing to help me out on this one...

Comment: Here is a link for self host wcf service.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx

Comment: thanks for the direction ! It looks like thats what iam looking for :) Maybe i can make it working, thanks :)